# Wrap a LINQ datacontext and non linq stored procedure into a transaction?

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-sql, transactions, asp.net-membership

Is it possible to wrap some "external" API code AND a LINQ data context into a transaction? In my case, I want to wrap the ASP.NET 2.0 Membership API calls AND my own LINQ operations into a transaction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do this if you wrap everything within a [TransactionScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx) object.